# Why does running a plot in a secondary thread works the first time (with warning), but fails the second time (with error)?

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib

For some quick tests (this code will evolve later anyway, so a temporary solution is ok), I need to use Matplotlib in a `thread`, and **not** the main thread.

Usually we have this warning but it works anyway:

> UserWarning: Starting a Matplotlib GUI outside of the main thread will likely fail.

Here it is indeed the case.

However, when the first plot is closed, and we do the same **a second time**, then it totally fails with not a warning, but an **error**:

> RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

**Is there a way to make the following code work?** (even if it is not the recommened matplotlib way)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import threading, time

def visualization_thread():
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        l1, *_ = ax.plot(y1, color='r', label="1")
        fig.show()
        fig.canvas.flush_events()
        while running:
            l1.set_ydata(y1)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
            fig.canvas.flush_events()
            plt.pause(0.020)

def data_thread():
    global y1, y2, y3
    while running:
        y1 = np.random.rand(100)
        time.sleep(0.020)

running = True   # !!! WARNING but it still works
threading.Thread(target=data_thread).start()
threading.Thread(target=visualization_thread).start()
time.sleep(4)
running = False
time.sleep(2)

running = True  # !!! FAILS, why?
threading.Thread(target=data_thread).start()
threading.Thread(target=visualization_thread).start()
```

Comment: It would help if you could explain _why_ you say that you "need to use Matplotlib in a thread, and not the main thread" (in your post) Because right now the most obvious solution is to do things properly and run the plot in your main thread.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans 1/2 Let's say the script is a **server** that handles totally different things (e.g. acquisition/handling of data) , I just need a temporary solution to be able to plot in realtime some informations in matplotlib (this will evolve later), thus the need to do this in a thread other than the main thread (the main thread is busy with other things).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans 2/2 With my MCVE, do you get something working for the first call (with a warning), and an error for the secound round, too?

Comment: Please put those details [in your post](/help/how-to-ask) because you're not just answering "me", you're providing SO folks with more details about your problem. With that said: why would you do that in the same program? Can you not just write a separate visualizer that you can just send data to? (via a socket, or a synced file, or a db, etc?) Because it sounds like your visualizer is not "part" of your real program.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I will exactly do this, but this will require some time for a global solution. I'm just looking for a simple/hackish/temporary/working-for-today-solution. It seems that "it kind of works", see the first call. But I don't know which the second call fails.

Comment: Seems the problem is that you run it once in one thread, and later on in a different thread. Can you keep that first thread alive, so that you always run `visualization_thread` in the same one?

Comment: @DanMašek This might be the reason indeed. Currently it would be complicated in my global setup to persist the thread just in case some plotting will be needed later, but I'll think about this. (Anyway, as said before, later, a whole different, cleaner, solution will be written - just looking for a quick and dirty solution for today)

Comment: Note that it's _real_ easy to set up a quick and dirty socket connection. Python has websockets built in, you pretty much just copy-paste [the example code](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) from the python docs, and done. Your visualizer runs a bare-bones websocket server, your program creates a websocket client connection to that, and then you can dump as much data from your program to the visualizer as you want in real-time. (probably _less_ work than trying to thread things =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes I've already worked with websockets, I agree, but I wanted to try something very basic first, since the system will evolve to something else anyway in a few days. (Was looking for the quick and dirty 2-line solution to make the MCVE here work)

Comment: If you're looking for something basic as hold-over, choosing to use threads is the exact opposite of basic, it's pretty much guaranteed "a few lines of code up front but then an entire day of then figuring out deadlock, race conditions, zombies or early exits, and all that other fun stuff" compared to copy-pasting the websocket code and being done in 15 minutes tops =)

Comment: (especially if you're on a version of Python that still has the global interpreter lock., which is pretty much all of them right now. which means you might get "thread" rather than "threads", with only one thread allowed to run at a time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed that adding `plt.close()` at the end of the visualization thread solves the problem.

Again, this is a temporary solution, since `matplotlib` is not threadsafe anyway.